# На новом компьютере часто перезагружаеться система windows 7 Ultimatum

Tags: windows

На новом компьютере часто перезагружаеться система windows 7 Ultimate.Помогите, что сделать. Компьютер мощный новый, а перезагружается. Системе 3 дня, как поставил.

Comment: Перезагрузка как происходит? Это синий экран смерти или как-будто резко пропадает питание?

Comment: возможно проблема с железом? протести память

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, хорошо ли закреплен кулер охлаждения, если он запылен, снять и почистить, при установке использовать термопасту (рекомендуется).

Comment: Ребята он новый я уже все проверил ни пылинки . а она падла серовно

Comment: Проблема может быть аппаратная: блок питания или цепь питания на материнской плате.

Answer (score 1):

Если при перезагрузке появляется экран смерти, то надо посмотреть какой файл вызывает ошибку. Скорее это какой-либо драйвер. У меня раз в несколько недель комп перезагружается из-за USB-модема. На синем экране смерти пишется имя файла драйвера. Возникает когда надолго оставляю закачку торрентов. При этом он сильно нагревается. Посмотреть имя файла можно во время синего экрана. Если не успеваешь увидеть, то надо отключить в автоматическую перезагрузку: Панель управления - Система и безопасность - Система - Дополнительные параметры системы - Дополнительно - Загрузка и восстановление:Параметры - Снять галочку: Выполнять автоматическую перезагрузку.

Также можно посмотреть события в системном журнале. Как смотреть описывал [тут](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1305/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB).

Answer (score 0):

Что делать - скорее всего систему сносить и ставить другую. К сожалению, мощность и новизна ПК не критерий. А найти семерку особого труда не составляет.

Comment: У меня лицензия типо ... я уже перезагрузку автоматическую отключил. И все равно.

Comment: Дело не в лицензии,а в целостности дистра и не пользоваться сборками,а установить чистую - пускай даже не лицензионную, и потом уже обвешивать ее

Answer (score 0):

в давние времена, когда стоял ещё XP наблюдалась похожая картина, при каждой загрузке системма тестировалась на ошибку. три мастера не могли определить, что с ней. и только четвертый снял все планки памяти и ставил по одной. когда поставил третью из четырех и очередной раз перезагрузил системма опять стала себя тестировать. выяснилось. что планка битая. согласен с Иваном